# Google Charts multiple series in one table

Tags: mysql, google-visualization

I have a dataset that I get from a mySQL database. This set contains data for different series of data.

How can I show this data on a google charts linechart as different sets? The data I retrieve looks as follows:

```
[date          Value    SeriesName]
[2015-10-11    23.4      Series 1]
[2015-10-11    20.3      Series 2]
[2015-10-12    24.8      Series 3]
[2015-10-15    20.0      Series 2]
[2015-10-16    19.8      Series 1]
...
```

Thanks
Rupert

Comment: One-time operation, or dynamically on demand? If dynamic on-demand, what are you using server-side?

Comment: I need it to be dynamically on-demand. I use jQUERY to retrieve the data from the (linux) server

Answer (score 0):

You need to pivot the data, 
1. Use the sql function (not that user friendly)
2. Manually: join each series in it's own subquery, so it has its own column. Then charts will recognise each column as its own series

eg:

```
select
t.date,
t1.value as 'Series 1',
t2.value as 'Series 2',
t3.value as 'Series 3'
from table t
left join (select date,value from table where seriesname='series 1') t1 on t1.date=t.date
left join (select date,value from table where seriesname='series 2') t2 on t2.date=t.date
left join (select date,value from table where seriesname='series 3') t3 on t3.date=t.date
```